# which means double 2 points 192.168.1.2::3 in a vnc connection

Tags: ip, connection, vnc, software

install real vnc to make connections to a windows server but at the time of accessing me it appears that to access I must approach it with the route

```
192.168.1.2::3
```

I understand that `:` after the IP means port but `::` what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/_downloads/VNC_User_Guide.pdf):

> If you know that *VNC
>   Server* is listening on a port between 5901 and 5999, append a colon
>   (:) and an identifying number (1 through 99) to the network address,
>   for
>   example:
> johndoe:1
> 192.168.5.54:1
> [2001:db8::1]:1
> If
>   you know that *VNC Server* is listening on any other port, append a
>   double colon (::) and the full port number to the network address, for
>   example:
> johndoe::6001
> 192.168.5.54::6001
> [2001:db8::1]::6001

Based on what the manual states, your vncserver listens on port 3.